# PHP (Content-type: text/plain)

Tags: php, json, header

After adding PHP `header("Content-type: text/plain");` a space is added.
I use it for pretty JSON.

I need this:

> {
>        "code":"200" }
>   }

But I get this:

> {
>        "code":"200" }
>   }

Comment: Very, very hard for folks to help you if you don't quote more of your code.

Comment: @ user: The edit is great, but as the important thing is where your `<?php ... ?>` tags are, we need to see the full page (as you clearly have a nice, self-contained example there).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only difference between those two blocks of code is a single space before the first `{`... is that what the source of concern is? Also - do you realize that what you've put out here is invalid JSON to begin with?

Comment: You must add more detail from your code, If you really want people to help out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your PHP page closely, you probably just have whitespace in it (outside of your PHP tags) that you don't realize. (And you have an extra `}` in your JSON...)

Comment: First i have two spaces, when I checked it, I have removed one and now  this space, because Content-type is setted, but I need it.

Comment: In general, ensure `<?php` is first thing in your php file and remove `?>`.

Comment: @user1821941: The point is that every character outside of `<?php ... ?>` blocks is sent to the client. So you need to make sure there are no characters outside of those blocks. At all.

Comment: Thanks, really stupid bug. In fuctions I have missed to remove a space. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.4 or greater you can use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag.

However I also think that you might have a whitespace before the print, if not in your main page, maybe in `functions.php`.

Comment: I have updated php5 yesterday, but this `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag isn't work and I use function.

Comment: You should check via `phpinfo()` your PHP version. That flag works with PHP 5.4 or greater.